# Type refinement "forgetting" the value within a statement?

Tags: typescript, refinement-type

Moving from flow I am often refining `mixed` types to some better format. In typescript I use `unknown` instead of mixed. Resulting in the following codepiece for error handling:

```
type err = {
    cause: unknown,
    msg: string,
}

if (typeof err.cause === 'object' && 
    err.cause !== null && 
    'incomplete' in err.cause && 
    Array.isArray(err.cause.incomplete)) {
    something(err.cause.incomplete[0]);
    //..something
}
```

As far as I can tell this should work? - I'm first checking if the `cause` is a valid object, and then test if `incomplete` is inside it.

However an error shows at the `Array.isArray`:

```
Error:(26, 37) TS2339: Property 'incomplete' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

So what's making typescript "forget" the previous refinement, and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It does refine `unknown` to `object`, but you can't access arbitrary fields on an object, and `'incomplete' in err.cause` doesn't actually refine the type. To do that, you'll need a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Example:

```js
function f(o: object) {
    if ("incomplete" in o) {
        console.log(o.incomplete); // error
    }
    if (hasIncomplete(o)) {
        console.log(o.incomplete); // okay
    }
}

function hasIncomplete(o: object): o is HasIncomplete {
    return o.hasOwnProperty("incomplete");
}

interface HasIncomplete {
    incomplete: any;
}
```